# python for loop with updated values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with over 10k rows. I need to iterate through every row and do math based on the value of the previous row after it's updated. For loop is very slow.

Example DF:

```
a  b  c
1  2  3
2  3  4
3  4  5
```

for loop example:

```
for i in range(1,len(DF)):
  DF['b'] = DF['b'].[i-1]+DF['c']
```

I also tried

```
DF['b'] = DF['b'].shift(1)+DF['c']
```

but that won't use the updated value 'b'.

What is the best way to do such calculations?

ANSWERED:
loc and iloc helps.
The best way to do this is:

```
for i in range(1, len(DF)):
  DF.loc[i, 'b'] = DF.loc[i-1, 'b'] + DF.loc[i, 'c']
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `range(1,len(DF)):`?

Comment: The particular math you wish to do is important. If it is simply addition, you could use `cumsum`. If it is more complicated, there may be no way to avoid looping over the rows. In that case, you may need [Cython to boost performance](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#enhancing-performance).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 UPDATED. I was translating an R script to Python.

Comment: @unutbu The actual usage is more complicated math than this example, so I cannot use cumsum. Is there no better way than a for loop?

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing the actual math.

Comment: @unutbu I'm aggregating on two different columns so it is not a cumsum problem. The idea is the same as the one I posted but with more columns.

Comment: You need to be specific. Given your description the obvious question is why not call `cumsum` on both columns? A [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful. The devil is in the details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iloc

```
for i in range(1,len(DF)):
    DF.iloc[i]['b'] = DF.iloc[i-1]['b']+DF.iloc['i']['c']
```

Comment: This helped a little, but yields the `SettingWithCopyWarning`. I changed it to
    `DF.loc[i, 'b'] = DF.loc[i-1, 'b']+DF.loc['i', 'c'] ` and it's much faster.

Comment: Yes, you can also turn off the `SettingWithCopyWarning` using following command `pa.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn' `